# Structure of CCl₂

Tags: molecular-structure, vsepr-theory

I read that $\ce{CCl2}$ is non-polar. When I read about the reason on the net it stated that $\ce{CCl2}$ has a linear structure, but according to VSEPR theory it should have bent V-shaped geometry. Please clarify.

Comment: Why bother about this compound ? It is not stable. It only exists as an intermediate in some reactions. You will never be able to store it in a flask with label CCl2. So why ?

Comment: @Sameer My apologies, I misread the compound formula as dichloromethane, so I deleted my comment as irrelevant. Sorry for the confusion, this is a nice question. Have a look at [What is the hybridization state of E (= Sn, C) in ECl₂?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49192) and the paper Martin refers to in his answer: https://doi.org/10.1039/b202865d, this should answer your question (yes, CCl₂ is bent).

Comment: @Maurice "*Science isn't about why; it's about why not*".

Comment: VSEPR theory is great, but only up to a certain point. You should probably not use it for "exotic" species like carbenes. Even though it happens to give the right result in this case, that's probably more of a coincidence than anything.