# Bond angle order of SF2, OF2, HOF

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond

> Arrange the following componds in the increasing order of bond angle.
>   $$\ce{HOF,~OF2,~SF2}$$

I know that bond angle of $\ce{SF2}$ will be less than the bond angle of $\ce{OF2}$ because of larger size of sulfur atom.

How can I compare $\ce{HOF}$ with the other two? Since $\ce{H}$ is less electronegative than $\ce{O}$,  the bond pair of $\ce{O - H}$ bond will be more closer to $\ce{O}$. The opposite happens for $\ce{O - F}$ bond. In $\ce{SF2}$ both bond pairs are near $\ce{F}$ so the bonds can come closer to each other.

Comment: [This answer](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33818/bond-angles-for-the-hydrides/33824#33824) explains why $\ce{SF2}$ will have a bond angle close to $90^\circ$ and $\ce{OF2}$ will have a bond angle closer to $109.5^\circ$. For similar reasons, $\ce{HOF}$ will have a bond angle closer to $109.5^\circ$. However, comparing $\ce{HOF}$ and $\ce{OF2}$, you need to compare both the size difference of $\ce{H}$ and $\ce{F}$ and their electron-density (not just electronegativity).

Comment: @BenNorris it given in Wikipedia that HOF bond angle is 97.2 and that in SF2 is 98.

Comment: Now, that I would not have expected. Interesting.

Comment: @SafdarFaisal I think this post might already have the answer to the question: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/119034/why-is-the-binding-angle-of-hof-lesser-than-that-of-h2o-despite-the-lone-pairs

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti, that answer is based on speculation and doesn't have a reference attached to it.  Note: $\ce{OF2}$ is predictable, but the trend comparing HOF and $\ce{SF2}$ is not that easily seen. Bounty will be awarded if you can  cite a reference so as to why the bond angle of HOF is unexpectedly  low..

Answer (score 4):

When considering bond angles of molecules of main group ($\ce{\angle A-X-B}$) there are several different factors to consider:

1. The row of the the central atom $\ce{X}$ determines the energy difference between the valence s and p orbital, which determines the extent of mixing (or hybridisation if you wish)
2. The sizes of A and B, because steric repulsion, A and B would want to stay away from each other the bigger they get.
3. Electronegativities of the A and B. More electronegative atoms would prefer to have a bond with higher p-character. (This is explained in VSEPR model with the bond pair being drawn away from the central atom)
4. Other forces betwen A and B

The bond angles of the molecules mentioned in question are:
$$\begin{array} {c|c}\hline  & \text{bond angle} \\ \hline \ce{OF2} & 103.2^\circ \\ \hline \ce{SF2} & 98^\circ \\ \hline \ce{HOF} & 97.2^\circ \\ \hline  \end{array}$$

The difference between $\ce{OF2}$ and $\ce{SF2}$ would be usually explained with the fact that oxygen is in 2nd period so, the energy difference between $\mathrm{2s}$ and $\mathrm{2p}$ is low which means it is $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridised. (Or at least close to $\mathrm{sp^3}$). Whereas sulfur is in the 3rd period so, the energy difference between $\text{3s}$ and $\text{3p}$ is high which means it is almost unhybridised and the bonds are formed by almost pure $\text{3p}$ (which is why the angle is closer to $90^\circ$).

The bond angle of $\ce{HOF}$ is however, unusally small. This is difficult to explain and is usually attributed to the electrostatic attraction between $\delta+\;$ of H and $\delta-\;$ of F, which pulls the H and F close together.

From Chemistry of the Elements <sup>[1]</sup>,

> Spectroscopic data establish a nonlinear structure with $\ce{H-O}$ $\pu{96.4 pm}$, $\ce{O-F}$ $\pu{144.2 pm}$, and bond angle $\ce{H-O-F}$ $97.2^\circ$: this is the smallest known bond angle at an unrestricted O atom (cf. $\ce{H-O-H}$ $104.7^\circ$, $\ce{F-O-F}$ $103.2^\circ$). It has been suggested that this arises in part from eletrostatic attraction of the 2 terminal atoms, since NMR data lead to a charge of $\sim+0.5e$ on H and $\sim-0.5e$ on F.

So, the unusually small bond angle is likely from the electrostatic attraction. This type of effect is not just limited to $\ce{HOF}$, it is also found it other molecules. For instance, in hydrogen peroxide $\ce{H-O-O-H}$, the $\ce{H-O-O}$ angle is $94.8^\circ$ which is quite lower than the ideal tetrahedral angle, and has been attributed the electrostatic attraction between $\ce{O}$ and $\ce{H}$.<sup>[2]</sup>

As an aside, it should be noted that the above values of bond angles were measured in the gas phase. In solid phase, $\ce{HOF}$ has a slightly higher bond angle, at $101^\circ$.

References-

1. N. N. Greenwood, A Earnshaw, *Chemistry of the Elements*, 2nd ed., Butterworth-Heinemann, Oxford, 1998
2. E. Wiberg, A. F. Holleman, N. Wiberg, *Inorganic Chemistry*, Academic Press, 2001

Answer (score -4):

I looked up the net and found the following order-

HOF(97.2°)<SF<sub>2</sub>(98°)<OF<sub>2</sub>(103°)

(Of course, the values might not be exact but this is what I found on the net.)

Now, my POV-

Yes, your analogy that bond angle of OF<sub>2</sub>> SF<sub>2</sub> is correct. It's a direct result of [Drago's Rule](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/64613/104444).

The electron cloud in OF<sub>2</sub> will be shifted much towards the Fluorine atom. Bond pair-Bond pair repulsions are larger if the electron cloud is nearer to the central atom. But the correct reason is the distance between the electron clouds, not the "**near the central atom, away from it**" analogy.

In the HOF molecule, the cloud is more towards the central atom Oxygen in the H-O bond and towards F in the O-F bond. So the distance(very misleading term tho) between the two electron clouds is a bit larger than in the case of OF<sub>2</sub>. A larger distance means lesser repulsions and a smaller bond angle.

But the catch here is that the bond angle of SF<sub>2</sub> is slightly bigger than that of HOF. This is because the effect of electron cloud repulsions ( both electron clouds in both S-F bonds shifted towards Fluorine) and the size of sulfur atom ( Drago's rule) work against each other. Also, Drago's Rule doesn't apply much when the Electronegativity of the surrounding atom exceeds 2.5 which is the case with Fluorine ( 4- on the Pauling Scale).

You should also not forget the weak but existent back bonding in the S-F bond due to the presence of vacant d orbital in the Sulphur. The double-bond**ish** character leads to a **bit** stronger bond pair-bond pair repulsions. Why did I call the back bonding weak? It's because the Sulphur atom in SF<sub>2</sub> has two lone pairs that repel the electrons flowing in due to the back bond. Also adding on to that point, the 2p-3d back bond has appreciable overlap (more than 2p-3p) but it's still weak.

Drago's Rule is explained by the unfavorability of hybridization - **the energy required for hybridization is much larger than what will be obtained after hybridization**. In more EN atoms(>2.5) the net charge on the central atom is more positive which reduces the size of the central atom. Thus, the sizes ( read energies) of s, p, d orbitals become similar and hybridization is favorable only when atomic orbitals involved have similar energies.

Comment: 99% of the time backbonding is not required, and not valid anyway. Arguments based on s/p hybridisation should suffice. Have you come across any evidence that a 2p->3d bonding scheme is valid? Are there any studies to show whether the 3d orbital is occupied and to what extent?

Comment: Valid argument. Didn't think on those lines. Sure will look into it.

Answer (score -4):

$\ce{H-O-F}$ has a lower bond angle than both $\ce{F-S-F}$ and $\ce{F-O-F}$. The reason is probably that the lower electron density around $\ce{H}$ results in significantly less steric interaction between $\ce{H}$ and the lone pairs of the $\ce{F}$ atom. In both $\ce{SF2}$ and$\ce{ OF2}$, the two $\ce{F}$ atoms with high electron densities would tend to repel each other, thus resulting in a greater bond angle.
Hence the bond angle order comes out to be-
$$\ce{F-O-F \gt F-S-F \gt H-O-F}$$
Hope this helps!