# Hybridisation in phosphorus allotropes

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-structure, hybridization

The white phosphorus has a tetrahedral structure, like this:

[image: white phosphorus structure] [Image source: Wikipedia]

The red phosphorus, on the other hand, has a polymeric structure:

[image: red phosphorus structure] [Image source: google images]

Then what is the hybridisation state of P atoms in these allotropes?

For tetrahedral $\ce{P_4}$ in white phophorus, we can take $\ce{sp^3}$ hydbridisation, but some sites give information that P atom uses atomic 3p orbitals, as then the the angle strain is reduced from $\ce{109^\circ\rightarrow 60^\circ}$ to $\ce{90^\circ\rightarrow 60^\circ}$.

I can't find any website which gives information about the hybridisation state of red phosphorus. My chemistry textbook also does not give any information about this.

If you can give a reference to back up your answer, it would be useful to me.

Comment: Hybridisation is in our heads, ***not*** out there in the P allotropes.

Comment: Related: [Hybridization in PH3](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/14791/4945); [Why is the bond angle H-P-H smaller than H-N-H?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/14087/4945)

Comment: @IvanNeretin Here, I am considering that hybridization actually occurs in atoms, and trying to deduce whether the phosphorus atoms are hybridized or not.  I don't understand why you say that hybridisation is in our heads; because atomic orbitals undergo hybridisation if it produces lower energy state, and it does explain many properties of compounds.