# Why is bond angle of H2O greater than that of PH3?

Tags: bond

Central atom of water has two lone pairs and that of phosphine has one lone pair, then why isn't bond angle of water smaller?

Comment: If you added another hydrogen on water, the bond angle would likely decrease...

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14791/hybridization-in-ph3