# Bond angle in water vs in oxygen difluoride

Tags: molecular-structure

My teacher taught that bond angle $\ce{H-O-H}$ is larger than $\ce{F-O-F}$ due to less repulsion in the latter's bond pairs.
I know that bond angle $\ce{H-O-H}$ is $104.5^\circ$, but I'm confused with that of $\ce{F-O-F}$ because variable angles are given in articles on websites and in books. Some are $109.47^\circ$, $101.55^\circ$, $103.1^\circ$.

I want to know which bond angle is greater and why?

Comment: We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Answer (score 3):

Water has a bond angle of 105º and oxygen diflouride has a bond angle of 103.8º, which cannot be explained by repulsion since fluorine is larger than hydrogen<sup>$[1]$</sup>. This is phenomenon is, however, explained by [Bent's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bent%27s_rule):

> Bent's rule is that in a molecule, a central atom bonded to multiple groups will hybridise so that orbitals with more s character are directed towards electropositive groups, while orbitals with more p character will be directed towards groups that are more electronegative.

p orbitals are oriented 90º from each other, so orbitals with more p character have smaller angles between neighboring atoms. The effects of this phenomenon can also demonstrated by comparing bond lengths.

---

<sup>$[1]$ [Bent, H. A. *Chemical Reviews* **1961**, *61* (3), 288.](https://doi.org/10.1021/cr60211a005)</sup>

Comment: Where did you get the value for oxygen difluoride from? I couldn't find anything reliable.

Comment: On the Wikipedia page for Bent's Rule. I'm trying to find another source now.

Comment: So Bent's original paper actually uses 103.8º for the bond angle of oxygen difluoride. He cites Ibers, J. A., and Schomaker, V.: *J. Phys. Chem.* **1953**, *57*, 699 .

Answer (score 1):

On the DF-B97D3/def2-TZVPP level of theory the bond angle of water is $104.2^\circ$. Which matches up quite well, see [what is the bond angle of water?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/23806/4945) The bond angle of oxygen difluoride is $104.9^\circ$. Unfortunately I couldn't find a good source for an experimental value. (Also the [CCCBDB](https://cccbdb.nist.gov) currently only produces errors.)

The values are too close together to actually compare them on this level of theory. According to Bent's rule ([What is Bent's rule?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/15620/4945)) I would have expected the bond angle to be smaller in $\ce{OF2}$.

---

Maybe CCCBDB starts working again:

- Oxygen difluoride: https://cccbdb.nist.gov/alldata2x.asp?casno=7783417&charge=0
- Water:             https://cccbdb.nist.gov/alldata2x.asp?casno=7732185&charge=0