# How do we explain shapes of molecules using molecular orbital theory or do we even do that?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, valence-bond-theory

How do we explain shapes of molecules using molecular orbital theory  or do we  even do that ?

While reading about the theories to explain chemical combination and stabilities of compounds I read about VBT and MOT and how when VBT failed to explain certain facts MOT was introduced but i do not know how do we explain shape of molecules using MOT as we do in case of VBT .

Comment: See Walsh diagrams for a start

Comment: There is some information about predicting the shapes of small molecules  in this answer. http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/why-does-bond-angle-decrease-in-the-order-h%E2%82%82o-h%E2%82%82s-h%E2%82%82se/57973#57973