# Which molecule has maximum bond angle amongst BF₃, BCl₃ and BBr₃?

Tags: bond, molecular-structure, vsepr-theory

$\ce{Br}$ is the least electronegative from the given compounds. So, in $\ce{BBr3}$ the electrons will be the closest towards boron and thus due to electron-electron repulsions $\ce{BBr3}$ will have maximum bond angle.
Steric hindrance due to large size of bromine atom can be a factor too.

But the bond angles are same according to most of the websites.

Comment: I think for judging bond angles you should take a look at VSEPR structures for them. For all practical purposes, the changes due to electronegativity are negligible in most cases.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't get the motive of this question.

Comment: How would the bond angles be different?  If you have a ball and stick model, how do you move the bonds around so that you *don't* have an equilateral triangle (due to symmetry)?

Comment: @EricTowers I think the angles they're comparing between are the X-A-X vs X'-A-X' angles. Each of the X-A-X angles will necessarily be identical, but for different identities of A and X, you can change the angles (e.g. ammonia being pyramidal).

Comment: You might find this related answer interesting https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/why-does-bond-angle-decrease-in-the-order-h2o-h2s-h2se/57973

Comment: @Eric Towers Yes! It is now so obvious. Because the shape is trigonal planar for all of them, hence it must be 120*.

Answer (score 9):

With VSEPR theory you can predict the structures of $\ce{BX3}$. Since boron only has three valence electrons, all of which are used for σ-bonding to the halogen atoms, they arrange in a trigonal planar fashion. This means that all molecules $\ce{BF3}$, $\ce{BCl3}$, and $\ce{BBr3}$ have the same point group $D_\mathrm{3h}$. From this symmetry you can deduce that the bond angle is $\angle(\ce{X-B-X}) = 120^\circ$ for all of them.

Bent's rule won't have any effect on that.

There is also considerable π-backdonation in these molecules, but that only has an effect on bond lengths, not bond angles.