# Why is C-S-C bond angle in thiirane so small at 48.5 degrees?

Tags: stereochemistry, hybridization, vsepr-theory, bent-bond, ring-strain

Why is the C-S-C bond angle in thiirane (48.5 degrees) so much smaller than C-O-C bond angle in oxirane/epoxide (60 degrees).

[image]

[image]

Source: https://coek.info/pdf-three-membered-ring-heterocycles-.html

Comment: Because the sulfur atom is big, maybe?

Comment: How does that cause the bond angle to be smaller?

Comment: Because the non-bonding doublets are more cumbersome than the bonding doublets.  Sulfur is a large atom. It has two bonding electrons that are stretched between carbon and sulfur, and so are not really cumbersome. But it also has two non-bonding doublets that repell one another and are attracted by the sulfur nucleus. They also repell the stretched bonding electrons. As a consequence the angle between them is smaller than it is in a ordinary triangle

Comment: Similar question, possibly a dupe: [Why does bond angle decrease in the order H2O, H2S, H2Se?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/why-does-bond-angle-decrease-in-the-order-h2o-h2s-h2se)

Comment: This is pure planar geometry, no chemistry required. Try drawing a triangle with one side much smaller than the other two - what happens to the angle between the large sides? I guess the chemistry part comes in knowing that a C-C bond is much shorter than a C-S bond, as your table shows.