# Why cant H2O be linear?

Tags: bond, water, molecular-structure, hybridization, valence-bond-theory

My understanding is that a H2O molecule cannot be linear due to repulsions between the electrons of the non-bonding domains and the hydrogen:

[image]

However i was wondering why the structure could not take this form where the repulsions cancel out, resulting in a linear molecule:

[image]

Any answers would be helpful!

Comment: sp3 orbitals seem to bring more electrons closer to the nuclei than the p orbitals for the unshared pairs. It is a balance between attraction and repulsion.

Comment: There is a detailed answer here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/why-does-bond-angle-decrease-in-the-order-h2o-h2s-h2se/57973#57973