Why does H2S have different bond angles to H2O but same MO diagram
I have read that Hydrogen sulfide has lower bond angles than water. It is the same with series of pnictogen hydrides - ammonia has higher bond angles than phosphine. It says that there is no hybridization in for e.g hydrogen sulfide unlike water. I am not fully satisfied with this approach and I feel there must be a way to explain it using bond energies - MO theory (either canonical or localized). So I am wondering why H2S and H2O have such similar MO diagrams yet completely different bond angles

"No hybridisation" is the model approach that only tells you that the s and p orbitals are too far apart to allow for mixing of the molecular orbitals. Even though the reasoning is reverse since hybridisation is just a mathematical model. Molecular structure comes first.Bond dissociation energies are not a direct consequence of MOT, so I don't think there is much sense in trying to explain structure with those.

What is a MO way of explanining this then

i seriously cannot find it anywhere on posts. What is so different about  MO diagrams of H2S and H2O that changes their bond angles @Martin

I've written about this quite extensively here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/14115/4945 Same thing applies to $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{H2S}$.

There is also an answer here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/why-does-bond-angle-decrease-in-the-order-h2o-h2s-h2se/57973#57973

@Martin I have read the answers there but it is unclear to me. I would like a simple description about how h2s and h2o MO energies differ and how that reduces bond angle
