# How to compare the bond angle of ozone and nitrite anion

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

How do I compare the bond angle between $\ce{O_3}$ and $\ce{NO_2^-}$ ?

I've studied how to compare the bond angle when normal covalent bonds are present where the electrons are shared in the bond and so the concept of electron repulsion is used to judge the bond angle. But what about the case when one of the bonds is a coordinate bond? Is the process of finding the bond angles the same or is there anything else that happens in this case?

Comment: Your "the bond angle between $\ce{O3}$ and $\ce{NO^-_2}$" *reads like* the two were in close contact with each other.  At ambient conditions, this is unlikely as ozone is a gas, and the nitrite either dissolved in a solution, or in a salt, then in solid state.  *More* plausible is "the bond angle of $\ce{O3}$ and $\ce{NO^-_2}$", accounting for each individually.  Second, do you know about [resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance_(chemistry))?  The negative charge is not fix and isolated to stay on *one* of the oxygen atoms of the [nitrite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrite).

Comment: Changed the title as you said. I wanted to create a scenario where there was a coordinate bond and this "bent" sort of system and so I chose $\ce{NO_2^-}$. What I mainly wanted to know was that how these rules apply in case there are coordinate bonds?

Comment: To *record* an angle $\angle{} (A,B,C)$ along A, B (the apex), and C, you need 3 points (here: atoms); regardless if these belong to an ion or neuter molecule. At present, your question lacks some clarity to see if it addresses [VSEPR theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSEPR_theory) or / and [AXE rules](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Map%3A_Chemistry_-_The_Central_Science_(Brown_et_al.)/09._Molecular_Geometry_and_Bonding_Theories/9.2%3A_The_VSEPR_Model) (illustrations incl. ions) where however lone pairs (= *potentially* a charge) and overall charges may matter.

Comment: @Buttonwood I wish to compare the O-O-O and the O-N-O angles. However, my primary concern is not with these specific compounds but rather the idea. In case of normal compounds with standard covalent bonds the bond angle can be compared using the quoted theory [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/99632/effect-of-electronegativity-on-bond-angles-in-nh3-and-nf3?noredirect=1&lq=1). And so I wanted to know what would happen if one of these bonds were coordinate. Please elaborate on where clarity is needed and I'll modify the question accordingly

Comment: Your question becomes even more confusing *for me* because VSEPR may be applied (with the same limitations as for compounds with "standard covalent bonds") equally on transition metal complexes, e.g., the diaminesilver(I)-complex (depicted, e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tollens%27_reagent)).  Count me out of this question.

Comment: @Ashish Consider a coordinate bond like a covalent bond and when you do draw the structure of $\ce{O_3 ,{ NO_2}^-}$ you will notice that the only apparent difference is the central atom. Considering a electronegativity arguement it can be shown that Bond angle of Ozone should be more.

Comment: This question is a complete riddle to me, and since I'm not the first, I'm going to close it. If you want to compare something, you measure it, then you compare it. I think what you are looking for are models of prediction for bond angles. The other problem is that there is no coordinate bond in either of these molecules, do your question doesn't make sense. Please include your understanding of bonding into your question. I guess there is a general misunderstanding there. Have you heard of molecular orbital theory?