# What effect does lone pair have on bond angle?

Tags: bond

I have read that the presence of lone pair decreases the bond angle.Shouldn't it increase the bond angle since there is repulsion between the electrons?

Comment: Lone pairs on central atom or on "non-central" atoms? In case of latter, your statement is true..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Application of the electronegativity effect on bond angles](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/131241/application-of-the-electronegativity-effect-on-bond-angles)

Answer (score 2):

Lone pairs on central atoms are like bulgy water filled balloons(diffused electron cloud of unshared electrons). They push down the neighbouring bond pairs causing a decrease in bond angle. In case of bond pair you may imagine the balloon being pulled (electron density attracted) by two persons from opp side (nuclear attraction of participating atoms) which reduces the bulgyness and hence bond pairs repel less than lone pairs.This is just my understanding. Hope my analogy is correct. If someone has a better answer I'll be happy to learn.

Comment: It varies tremendously on specific case. With metals, there's like no effect at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are considering the angle between the lone pair and the  bonds but bond angle is always between two bonds which will be reduced due to repulsion only as the bonds will get closer to each other.

Comment: @Loveforphysics bond angle is reduced due to the presence of lone pairs on non central atoms but not on central atoms.