# How do orbitals overlap in difluorosilane?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, bond, orbitals, atoms

In $\ce{SiH2F2}$ four orbitals of silicon $(\mathrm{3s},$ $\mathrm{3p}_x,$ $\mathrm{3p}_y,$ $\mathrm{3p}_z)$ overlap with two hydrogen $(\mathrm{1s})$ and two fluorine $(\mathrm{2p}).$
I want to know how these orbitals are paired for overlapping.
Is it based on strength of overlapping?

Answer (score 1):

A simple model for bonding in this molecule is taking $\ce {Si}$ to adopt $\ce {sp^3}$ hybridisation, as suggested from the tetrahedral geometry of the molecule. Subsequently, we can refine our model by applying Bent's rule (see more about it [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/what-is-bents-rule)), which tells us that $\ce {p}$ orbital character concentrates towards more electronegative substituents. Since the electronegativity of the elements has the following order: $\ce {F}$ > $\ce {H}$ > $\ce {Si}$ with Pauling electronegativity values of $\ce {3.98}$, $\ce {2.20}$ and $\ce {1.90}$ respectively, the $\ce {3p}$ character of $\ce {Si}$ would concentrate towards $\ce {F}$ while $\ce {3s}$ character concentrates towards $\ce {H}$. Thus, we would have $\ce {Si}$ using $\ce {sp^{3+x}}$ orbitals to form the bonds with $\ce {F}$ and $\ce {sp^{3-x}}$ to form the bonds with $\ce {H}$, where $x$ is some small value between $\ce {0}$ and $\ce {1}$.

Comment: It means one hydrogen approach to S orbital to form 1s-3p overlapping and other hydrogen will approach to p orbital of Si to form 1s-3p overlapping and the rest orbitals for fluorine to for 2p-3p.Is it correct?

Comment: @Private5661 Are you familiar with the theory of hybridisation? Have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_hybridisation