Is electronegativity a good argument to explain that bond angle of PH3 is smaller than of NH3?
I can't really understand the argument of my OpenCourseWare professor. She says that the atomic size difference between the two central atoms (P is "bigger" than N) explains the fact that the lone pair of $\ce{PH3}$ is much bigger than the one of NH$_3$ (and hence that the bond angle smaller for $\ce{PH3}$).
The only way I can get my head around this is by using an alternative explanation (whose validity I am not fully sure of).
My alternative explanation is that: since $\chi_N > \chi_P$, the phosphorus can't keep its lone pair close to him and that implies that the lone pair in $\ce{PH3}$ is more spacially distributed.
I guess the two explanations are equivalent, since the trends in size and in electronegativity are quite the opposite.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/what-is-bents-rule
