# Bond angles of dichlorine and dibromine monoxides

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, halides, reference-request, vsepr-theory

Most online sources suggest that the bond angle of $\ce{OBr2}$ is greater than the one of $\ce{OCl2}.$ It is explained by the electronegativity difference and electron repulsion within the VSEPR theory.

However, I think that the extent of back bonding would be more for $\ce{OCl2}$ and hence its bond angle should be greater. I have not been able to find any experimental data from reliable sources to verify my assumption.

Can someone please explain why I may be wrong and provide experimental data on bond angles along with it?

Comment: It is indeed larger, but the difference is only 1.1 degree. This is negligible and a lot of different effects could cause it.

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/18697/7475

Comment: I found some old data (J. Chem. Soc. A, p658,1968)  on $\ce{Cl2O}$ which gives an experimental bond angle of $111^{\circ}$ and bond length of $171$ pm. There are several sites that quote an angle of $105^{\circ}$ for $\ce{Br2O}$ but don't say whether this is measured.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### $\ce{F2O}$

| Phase | Method | ∠F−O−F | Reference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| solid (−223.8 °C) | powder x-ray diffraction | 98.0(1.5)° | [[1](https://doi.org/10.1039/C5DT02247A)], [ICSD-430183](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Ccdcid=430183&DatabaseToSearch=Published) |
| gas | microwave spectroscopy | 103.07(5)° | [[2](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1732240)] |

#### $\ce{Cl2O}$

| Phase | Method | ∠Cl−O−Cl | Reference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| solid (−183(2) °C) | single-crystal x-ray diffraction | 111.27(4)° | [[3](https://doi.org/10.1524/zkri.1998.213.4.237)], [ICSD-407768](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Doi=10.1524%2Fzkri.1998.213.4.237&DatabaseToSearch=Published) |
| gas | microwave spectroscopy | 110.96(8)° | [4] |

#### $\ce{Br2O}$

| Phase | Method | ∠Br−O−Br | Reference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| solid (−143 °C) | single-crystal x-ray diffraction | 114.2(2)° | [[5](https://doi.org/10.1002/zaac.19976230160)], [ICSD-50198](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Ccdcid=50198&DatabaseToSearch=ICSD) |
| gas | microwave spectroscopy | 112.24(20)° | [[6](https://doi.org/10.1002/zaac.19362260409)] |

There are differences for the bonding angles for gaseous and solid phases due to packing effects and intermolecular interactions.
The trend, however, remains: there is an increase of $\ce{X-O-X}$ angle from $\ce{F2O},$ $\ce{Cl2O}$ to $\ce{Br2O}$ as “*a result of increasing repulsion forces between the heavier halogen atoms*”. [[5](https://doi.org/10.1002/zaac.19976230160)] Overlay of the three structures obtained via x-ray diffraction is shown below by merging the location of the common oxygen atom and fixing the direction of a single $\ce{X-O}$ bond as well as the plane of each molecule:

[image: overlay of F2O, Cl2O, and Br2O]

#### References

1. Marx, R.; Seppelt, K. Structure Investigations on Oxygen Fluorides. *Dalton Trans.* **2015**, 44 (45), 19659–19662. DOI: [10.1039/C5DT02247A](https://doi.org/10.1039/C5DT02247A).
2. Pierce, L.; Jackson, R.; DiCianni, N. Microwave Spectrum, Structure, and Dipole Moment of $\ce{F2O}$. *J. Chem. Phys.* **1961**, 35 (6), 2240–2241. DOI: [10.1063/1.1732240](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1732240).
3. Minkwitz, R.; Bröchler, R.; Borrmann, H. Tieftemperatur-Kristallstruktur von Dichlormonoxid, $\ce{Cl2O}.$ *Zeitschrift für Kristallographie - Crystalline Materials* **1998**, 213 (4), 237–239. DOI: [10.1524/zkri.1998.213.4.237](https://doi.org/10.1524/zkri.1998.213.4.237).
4. Jackson, R. H.; Millen, D. J. Microwave Spectrum and Nuclear Quadrupole Coupling Coefficients for Chlorine Monoxide. *Proc. Chem. Soc.* **1959**, 10.
5. Hwang, I.-C.; Kuschel, R.; Seppelt, K. Structures of Bromine Oxygen Compounds. *Z. Anorg. Allg. Chem.* **1997**, 623 (1–6), 379–383. DOI: [10.1002/zaac.19976230160](https://doi.org/10.1002/zaac.19976230160).
6. Brenschede, W.; Schumacher, H.-J. Über Die Darstellung Und Einige Eigenschaften Eines Bromoxyds von Der Formel Br 2 O. *Z. Anorg. Allg. Chem.* **1936**, 226 (4), 370–384. DOI: [10.1002/zaac.19362260409](https://doi.org/10.1002/zaac.19362260409).

Answer (score 6):

I think steric effects may play a role in that chlorine atoms are smaller than bromine atoms. The bromine atomic radius is about 0.15 Å larger than the chlorine atomic radius. The larger bond angle can be in part explained by the need to accommodate the larger atoms.