# Bonding in PCl3

Tags: electrons, hybridization

Why is there a need to produce 4 equivalent sp3 hybrids? Wouldn't the 3s2 orbital be just fine on its own since it's spherical? Wouldn't it be easier to just be closer to the nucleus and not get involved in the 3p business? What would change if there were just three 3p orbitals? [image]

Comment: Yes, it works as you say.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14087/why-is-the-bond-angle-h-p-h-smaller-than-h-n-h